# Multiple Decorators in Decorator Pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, decorator

I have read a few tutorials on the topic of the Decorator Pattern similar to [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/479635/UnderstandingplusandplusImplementingplusDecoratorp) one. The basic example is a cake as in this tutorial, or a pizza as in other tutorials, and the decorators usually pass through values and modify them on the way (as in, every PizzaDecorator adds a small amount onto the price, thus returning the price of the pizza + all decorators). Now, that's certainly a nice example, but I am having a little trouble applying this to a less edible problem.
Suppose I have a base class that takes an input, according to which it modifies its state. Some of these state modifications cause an event to be raised which passes a value that could be considered the output. Now suppose the following features I'd like to individually add as decorators:

- A buffer for the output
- A history of the input
- Another type of input (e.g. interprets a set of characters as allowed byte input values)

Individually, they are not so much of a problem. The basic functionality of the class (i.e. the `TakeInput(byte input)` and `event Handler OutputAvailable`) reside in an interface that the base class as well as the decorators can inherit (do I really need the extra abstraction layer as in the given example, i.e. a separate interface for the Decorator classes which in turn inherits from the base interface?). Now, if I implement the input cache in a decorator, how do I add it in such a way, that the next decorator would not hide it again? If I added, say, a list to simply store the input and made it available via a property, that property would be hidden should I decide that I also want the output buffered. I could keep references to both decorators around- but that would be rather messy, or so I think, because I am going to need quite a bunch of decorators. If I derived from the Decorator, the inheritance mess that I initially wanted to avoid by applying this pattern would not go away. How do I solve this problem?

As requested, a piece of code that illustrates my problem. (Or so I hope, anyway)

```
public interface ISampleClass
{
    event OutputHandler OutputAvailable;
    void TakeInput(byte input);
}

public class BaseSampleClass : ISampleClass
{
    public event OutputHandler OutputAvailable;

    void TakeInput(byte input)
    { // To keep things simple:
        this.OutputAvailable(input);
    }
}

public class SampleClassInputCacheDecorator : ISampleClass
{
    private ISampleClass decoratedClass;
    private List<byte> inputCache;

    public event OutputHandler OutputAvailable;

    public SampleClassInputCacheDecorator(ISampleClass decoratedClass)
    {
        this.decoratedClass = decoratedClass;
        this.decoratedClass.OutputAvailable += (output) => {
            this.OutputAvailable(output);
        };
    }

    public List<byte> InputHistory { get { return this.inputCache; } }

    public void TakeInput(byte input) 
    {
        this.decoratedClass.TakeInput(input);
    }
}

public class SampleClassCharInputAdapterDecorator : ISampleClass
{
    private ISampleClass decoratedClass;

    public SampleClassCharInputAdapterDecorator(ISampleClass decoratedClass)
    {
        this.decoratedClass = decoratedClass;
        this.decoratedClass.OutputAvailable += (output) => {
            this.OutputAvailable(output);
        };
    }

    public void TakeInput(byte input) 
    {
        this.decoratedClass.TakeInput(input);
    }

    public void TakeInput(char input)
    {
        switch (input)
        {
            case 'a':
                this.TakeInput(27);
                break;
            case 'b':
            // You get the idea...
        }
    }
}

// Now, I want to use the base class and get the benefit of both decorators:
ISampleClass smpl = new BaseSampleClass();
smpl = new SampleClassInputCacheDecorator(smpl);
smpl = new SampleClassCharInputAdapterDecorator(smpl);

// Dang, the input gets cached, but I can't access the InputHistory property.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decorator is about altering the *contracted behavior*. You decorator adds completely new behavior, irrelevant in the context of the first one, and not being the part of the contract (the interface).

In fact `SampleClassInputCacheDecorator` is not a decorator - its actions are completely irrelevant from the `ISampleClass` point of view, as they don't influence `TakeInput` and `OutputAvailable` at all. It just depends on the `ISampleClass` chain, but does not "decorate" it. [Proxy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) seems more suitable here.